# How to get the primary color of any android app?

Tags: android, background-color, android-softkeyboard

I'm developing an Android keyboard app. I want to adapt its background-color to the current app's primary color when user is running my keyboard app in another app. Is it possible? If it is impossible, can you give me some other similar ideas?

Comment: get the dominant color from the current activity in the foreground.